# Is this a reasonable implementation of shouldComponentUpdate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I've been using React for years, but have never had a go-to way of implementing `shouldComponentUpdate`. Deep equality checks of nested props and state can be hard.

However, what's wrong with something like this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  const propsChanged = JSON.stringify(this.props) !== JSON.stringify(nextProps)
  const stateChanged = JSON.stringify(this.state) !== JSON.stringify(nextState)
  return propsChanged || stateChanged
}
```

Is this appropriate? Would this fail in unexpected ways?

I would think that `JSON.stringify` and direct string comparison would also be very fast operations.

Overall this approach seems sound to me, but I'm wondering if I'm missing any obvious pitfalls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would this fail in unexpected ways?

Probably, and it would almost certainly be slower than doing a deep object traversal to determine equality instead (since `JSON.stringify` has to do a deep object traversal *anyway*).

One way in which it can fail is that `JSON.stringify` can return different strings for equivalent objects (and this is specified behavior):

```js
const o1 = {a: 1, b: 2};
const o2 = {b: 2, a: 1};
const str1 = JSON.stringify(o1);
const str2 = JSON.stringify(o2);
console.log(str1);
console.log(str2);
console.log(str1 === str2);
```

...although I'll grant that's unlikely (at least) in the case of props and state in your React component. (It happens when non-integer-index properties on the objects get *created* in a different order. That's probably not going to happen with your top-level props or state properties, but what about subordinate objects? `this.setState({foo});` where `foo` is an object created in different ways at different times...)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about that. Are you aware of any safe way of easily achieving deep comparison?

Comment: @ischnmn - Fairly certain there's a question about that here on SO. Edit: [Lots, actually](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+deep+object+equality). :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not a reasonable implementation. `JSON.stringify` is a potentially slow operation.

You need to ask yourself if you really need a deep equality check. Why not just derive from `PureComponent`? It performs a shallow comparison, but wouldn't that be enough?

Comment: No, shallow comparison is not enough for my use case.

Comment: @ischnmn I believe you that you think this is the case, but can you explain why you think this is true? Maybe there is some refactoring waiting to happen?

Comment: That's outside the scope of the question. Deep equality is a core requirement.

Answer (score 0):

use loadash _.isEual method
[lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#isEqual)